# How to determine which webserver an image was served from?

Tags: image, optimization, cdn

How can I determine where an image was served from? (aka- how do I check to see if my CDN is working ?)

So far I have tried Inspect Element via the browser... not sure where to turn next.

Comment: What are you talking about???

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but please read the [asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Your question is unclear and your title is unhelpful

Answer (score 1):

Check the Network tab from your browser's developers tool. You can see what is coming to and what is going from your browser.

Comment: Thanks for sending me in the right direction... learned about timeline and event recording along the way, and I did figure out the difference my CDN is making... about 4x faster on some pages

Comment: Actually, it does provide a part of an  answer... The Developer tools in Firefox, Network tab, will show all the GET/POST, etc. requests...